# Showing same layer multiple times using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, symbology

I am using ArcMap.

I am working with a layer for which I have two separate values that I want to display using symbology. Ideally, I would like to duplicate the layer and place them side by side, with one image displaying symbology for the first variable and the other for the second variable. When I try to copy and paste the layer however, the labels for both variables show simultaneously on the same image.

How can I create two separate layers?

Comment: You've probably got a dozen options here, but why not turn off labels on the second layer?

Comment: Are they points, lines, or polygons? Coincident points are the hardest to deal with, but still not hard to handle.